# Why are my numpy files larger than the PNGs produced using the same array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to find a file type that can hold my arrays without taking up too much memory. I thought npy files would be less than PNGs but I guess I was wrong.

```
            depth_img = np.uint16(depth * 256)

            cv2.imwrite(name_dest_im, depth_img)
            np.save(name_dest_npy, depth_img)
```

[image]

Is it because I'm doing something wrong when exporting the array or is PNG the most efficient way to store uint16?

edit: It's a modified version of https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2/blob/master/test_simple.py

```
input_image = pil.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
            original_width, original_height = input_image.size
            input_image = input_image.resize((feed_width, feed_height), pil.LANCZOS)
            input_image = transforms.ToTensor()(input_image).unsqueeze(0)

            # PREDICTION
            input_image = input_image.to(device)
            features = encoder(input_image)
            outputs = depth_decoder(features)

            disp = outputs[("disp", 0)]
            disp_resized = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(
                disp, (original_height, original_width), mode="bilinear", align_corners=False)

            # Saving numpy file
            output_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0]
            name_dest_npy = os.path.join(output_directory, "{}_disp.npy".format(output_name))
            scaled_disp, _ = disp_to_depth(disp, 0.1, 100)


            name_dest_im = os.path.join(output_directory, "{}_disp.png".format(output_name))
            # Saving colormapped depth image
            map_resized_np = scaled_disp.squeeze().cpu().numpy()
            map_resized_np = cv2.resize(map_resized_np, (original_width, original_height))
            depth = 5.4 / map_resized_np
            depth = np.clip(depth, 0, 80)
            depth_img = np.uint16(depth * 256)

            cv2.imwrite(name_dest_im, depth_img)
            np.savez_compressed(name_dest_npy, depth_img)
```

Comment: Do you mean memory (RAM) or disk? Disk is nearly free these days... please be more specific as to your goals. Thank you.

Comment: try saving it as a type `uint8`

Comment: Saving to disk. I can't afford more memory. I can't save as uint8 because I calculate real-world distances using pixel values

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of this. Something that users can run without changing any code.

Comment: I was looking more of an explanation as to why PNG is more efficient than npy files but I provide the code above if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNGs are compressed, but `np.save` does not use compression. You can use `np.savez_compressed` to save a compressed array. If your data allow it, you can also save as uint8, as @vlovero suggests in a comment.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(128, 128, 3)).astype(np.uint16)

cv2.imwrite("random.png", img)
np.save("random.npy", img)
np.savez_compressed("random.npz", img=img)

f = np.load("random.npz")
img_loaded = f["img"]
# The loaded array is equal to the original.
np.testing.assert_array_equal(img, img_loaded)
```

The file sizes are as follows:

```
$ du -h random*
100K    random.npy
64K random.npz
64K random.png
```

Comment: When I load the files, can I do np.load or is there some special function I need to do?

Comment: I'm still getting PNG as more efficient than npz files